# suggestions on word-choice for "the smell of roses"

Tags: word-choice, grammar, idioms, vocabulary, dialogue

Can someone suggest another way to say "the smell of roses in the air", please.Is "the aroma of roses" mean the same?

Comment: Did you look in a thesaurus? You'll find a number of words that will work (and a dictionary will be able to tell you what they mean).

Comment: No, I didn't. I'm new in this website so you thank for telling me about this :)

Answer (score 2):

I think about **Fragrance**:

> **a.** The quality of having a pleasant odor: the fragrance of the ocean breeze.
>   **b.** A sweet or pleasant odor; a scent.
>    A substance, such as a perfume or cologne, designed to emit a pleasant odor.
>
> Synonyms: aroma, bouquet, perfume, redolence, scent
>   These nouns denote a pleasant or sweet odor: the fragrance of lilacs; the aroma of sizzling bacon; the bouquet of a fine wine; the perfume of roses; the redolence of fresh coffee; the scent of newly mown hay.
>   <sub>[The American Heritage Dictionary](https://ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?id=F5295500)</sub>

Comment: In the future, please [cite your sources](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/referencing), otherwise it is plagiarism. I've done it for you this time.